# How to add subit action to an image

Tags: html, css

I am supposed to add submit action to an image.So on the main page,i have done `<input type="submit" class="go-button" name="submit"/>` in 
and in css i have written

```
.go-button {
 margin-right:7px;
 background: transparent url(../images/go.gif);
 width:26px;
 height:20px; 
 border:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

But the problem is I am getting Submit query on the GO image.
I dont want that.
Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submit button can also be defined as an image:

```
<input type="image" src="image.png" alt="Alt text" />
```